# Updating state array using Spread operator in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, spread

I am trying to update a state array after accepting the input from Form. State already has events object in it with data and I want to accept data from the form and append to the existing list. I'm able to do console log of the newEvents (data from form in another component), but using the spread operator unable to update the existing  state by appending it.

> //getting newEvent object from form in another component. // events is
> an array in state which has data  //priniting the existing array
> without appending newEvent //printing data from form (newEvent)
> properly

```
testmethodfornow = (newEvent) => (
    { ...this.state.events, events: [newEvent, ...this.state.events] },
    console.log(this.state.events),
    console.log(newEvent)
)
```

I want newEvent to be added to event :( Can anyone please help ?

NewEvent structure:

`const newEvent = { IdText: uuid(), EventName, Venue, Time };`

events array structure in state:

```
state = {
    flag: false,
    title: "State Check",
    events: [
        {
            IdText: '1',
            EventName: 'New Year Party 2022',
            Venue: 'The Social',
            Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM',
            Date: ''
        },
        {
            IdText: '2',
            EventName: 'StandUp Comedy',
            Venue: 'ShilpaRamam',
            Time: '8:00 PM- 1:00AM',
            Date: ''

        }]
}
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using class components, use `setState` to update the state. In this case `events` is a field of the state. So you can spread rest of the `state` instead of `state.events`.

```
  addNewEvent(){
    setState({...this.state, events: [newEvent, ...this.state.events]})
  }
```